# Select parent row and its children and grand children

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table of comments and I am trying to accomplish being able to select the root comments (`ParentCommentId = 0) and then out of the parent comments I got back, also select me all of the children and those children's children and so on

For example, I would get back the row for `CommentId = 1038`. I would also want its child (`CommentId = 1039`) because the `ParentCommentId = 1038`, and then also `CommentId = 1040` because it's `ParentCommentId = 1039` and etc..

[image]

I tried the below query as I think I am on the right direction.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         c.CommentId,
         c.PostId,
         c.Comment,
         c.ParentCommentId,
         c.CommentDateTime
     FROM 
         [gallery].[Comments] c
     INNER JOIN 
         [player].[Players] p ON p.UserId = c.UserId 
     WHERE 
         c.PostId = 32
         AND ParentCommentId = 0) AS ParentComments
JOIN
    (SELECT 
         c.CommentId,
         c.PostId,
         c.Comment,
         c.ParentCommentId,
         c.CommentDateTime
     FROM 
         [gallery].[Comments] c
     INNER JOIN 
         [player].[Players] p ON p.UserId = c.UserId 
     WHERE 
         c.PostId = 32
         AND ParentCommentId != 0) AS ChildComments ON ParentComments.CommentId = ChildComments.ParentCommentId
```

But I am getting back wrong data for sure, like the child on same row as parent, ideally I would like the children to be separate rows.  It also only goes 1 child deep and am definitely missing a lot of comments (there are way more than the 5 pictured below). I seem to only be getting a root comment and it's first child and not any that don't have children or the root comments grand children.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're likely missing data because you used an `inner join`. This is problematic for cases where the grand-parent isn't in the table, e.g.:

- for `CommentID = 1036` we are not given the grand-parent/parent in the data extract
- for any comment at level 1 of the hierarchy (i.e. Parent = 0)

Using a `left join` should fix this.

## Data used

```sql
declare @target table (
    CommentID int
    ,PostID int
    ,Comment varchar(200)
    ,ParentCommentId int
);

insert into @target
values
    (1036, 32, 'Que?', 1033)
    ,(1037, 32, 'What up mane', 1035)
    ,(1038, 32, 'Hi', 0)
    ,(1039, 32, 'Can you see me?', 1038)
    ,(1040, 32, 'Test', 1039)
    ,(1041, 32, 'T', 1038)
    ,(1042, 32, 'Yoooo', 0)
    ,(1043, 32, 'Test?', 1042)
    ,(1044, 32, 'Test 1', 1039)
    ,(1045, 32, 'Test 2', 1039)
;
```

## Getting the Hierarchy

A simple hierarchy table can be built showing the three levels of

```sql
select 
    GrandParentCommentID = isnull(b.ParentCommentID, 0)
    ,a.ParentCommentID
    ,a.CommentID 
from @target as a 
left join @target as b on a.ParentCommentId = b.CommentID
```

## Full Answer

```sql
with Hierarchy as (
    select 
        GrandParentCommentID = b.CommentID
        ,a.ParentCommentID
        ,a.CommentID 
    from @target as a 
    inner join @target as b on a.ParentCommentId = b.CommentID
)
select 
    hier.GrandParentCommentID
    ,hier.ParentCommentID
    ,hier.CommentID
    ,details.Comment
from Hierarchy as hier
inner join @target as details on details.CommentID = hier.CommentID
order by
    hier.GrandParentCommentID
    ,hier.ParentCommentID
```

## Results

[image]

## Bonus

If you want to get the level as a column, you can use a recursive CTE as below (I'm sure there's better ways):

```sql
;with Hierarchy as (
    select
        GrandParentCommentID = 0
        ,ParentCommentID = 0
        ,CommentID
        ,hier_level = 1
    from @target where ParentCommentID = 0

    union all
    select 
        GrandParentCommentID = h.ParentCommentID
        ,t.ParentCommentID
        ,t.CommentID
        ,hierarchy_level = h.hier_level + 1
    from Hierarchy as h
    inner join @target as t on t.ParentCommentId = h.CommentID
)
select * from Hierarchy
```

Add a grand-grand-child for demonstration:

```sql
insert into @target values (1045, 32, 'Test 2', 1039);
```

Results: 
[image]

Comment: wow that was a great answer, very detailed and was able to understand what was going on... thank you!